# Pass my class with ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have this:

```
ng-class="serv.name == xxx ? 'class1' : class2
```

And I would like to do this:

```
ng-click="functionName(ng-class)"
```

with this in js:

```
$scope.functionName(ng-class){
  if(ng-class == class1)...
}
```

Can I pass the class with ng-click to add parameters to this class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why you need pass the `ng-class` object controller function? You can call the `ng-class` model object directly in your controller. 
So you don't need to pass the `ng-class` object in your `ng-click` function. call the model name directly  in your controller with **`$scope`** object, like

```
if($scope.serv.name== "class1")
 {
   // code
   return false
 }
  // other code
```

Comment: Why down vote? can you share with me for the reason?